# SqlQuery returning ora-00911 invalid character although the query generated runs well in Oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, entity-framework-6

I am trying to get the next sequence number from oracle database 11g. I have used different methods to get the data from database it is still saying invalid character. the same query generated runs well on the oracle database.
Primary key (sequenceId, sequenceNumber). On each sequenceId there will be a separate counter. I am using generic type TEntity which will be passed by controlerl.

```
public virtual async Task<BaseResult<int>> GetNextSequenceAsync(string sequenceId)
        {
            var sequenceIdField = typeof(SequenceIdDatabaseFields).GetField(typeof(TEntity).Name).GetValue(null);
            var table = typeof(SequenceDatabaseTable).GetField(typeof(TEntity).Name).GetValue(null);
            var column = typeof(SequenceDatabaseColumn).GetField(typeof(TEntity).Name).GetValue(null);
            //var query = new OracleCommand("SELECT NVL(MAX(" + column  + ") + 1, 1) AS "+ column+" FROM "+ table+" WHERE "+ sequenceIdField+" = '"+ sequenceId + "';");
            var query = "SELECT NVL(MAX(" + column + ") + 1, 1) AS " + column + " FROM " + table + " WHERE " + sequenceIdField + " = '" + sequenceId + "';";
            //var nextValue = int.Parse(query.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            var nextValue = await _context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query).FirstAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            return GetBaseResult(nextValue, ResultTypes.Ok);
        }
```

The query evaluates to

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(CMNT_SEQ_NBR) + 1, 1) AS CMNT_SEQ_NBR FROM CASE_CMNT WHERE CASE_NBR = '00100283000807215100';
```

Comment: Can you post the complete query as well, as it is when passed to the server?

Comment: What is the exact value of `query`?

Comment: Check other answert to [ORA-00911](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ora-00911) most probably you should remove the trailing  semicolon (`...+ sequenceId + "';"`) from your *query* string. And yes running the query **with semicolon** from IDE is fine;)

Answer (score 1):

@Marmite Bomber was bang on target. Never even dreamt that this could be the problem. 
I executed the query after removing the ";". It worked perfectly.

```
var query = "SELECT NVL(MAX(" + column + ") + 1, 1) AS " + column + " FROM " + table + " WHERE " + sequenceIdField + " = '" + sequenceId + "'";
```

Comment: SQL has no semicolon. Client tools use it as a separator, but it's not sent to the database.